# Speech synthesis keeps speaking on page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, text-to-speech, speech-synthesis

In one of my PHP project I have integrated speech synthesis. On click of button I am calling a function for text to speech. Like,

```
var newUtterance = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance();
newUtterance.text = 'Test Message';
window.speechSynthesis.speak(newUtterance);
```

This works perfect. But when user refreshes the page it keeps speaking where I want to stop it on page load. I tried with,
On document ready function,

```
if (window.speechSynthesis.speaking) {
   window.speechSynthesis.cancel();
}
```

and also like, On page load function,

```
var newUtterance = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance();
newUtterance.text = '';
window.speechSynthesis.speak(newUtterance);
```

But not working. Working on chrome browser. Thanks in advance.

Comment: It might be that a new page is a new context and so you can't cancel from there. Maybe try to cancel it before leaving the page, for example, on `beforeunload`.

Comment: Put the cancel command in the javascript outside any function or if statement, so that it runs when the page and javascript file is loaded. If there is nothing speaking a cancel command does no harm.